# Check If user exist in /etc/passwd, If exist create new one with prefix

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, useradd

Kinda stuck here, did not found any solutions.

Check If user exist in /etc/passwd, If exist create new one with prefix new_the_existed_one

```
#!/bin/bash

myuser="/home/yakyak/Desktop/Exercises/newusers.txt"

sed '/^[ \t]*$/d' $myuser | while read -r line
do
        name="$line"
        # adduser --disabled-login --gecos "" $name
        # check if user exist
        isthere=$(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep "$name")

        # if user was added then make insert record into log file
        if [[ "$isthere" == "$name" ]]
        then
            echo "User already exist, creating new user.."
            adduser --disabled-login 
        # adduser --disabled-login --gecos " " $name
        fi   
done
```

Comment: How does `newusers.txt` look like? Where exactly are you stuck - please try to describe your problem in more detail. In your script: what part does work well, where does it fail?

Comment: don't grep `/etc/passwd` directly, use `getent` instead.   e.g. `getent passwd "$name" | cut -d: -f1`.   Also, your `isthere` variable isn't needed at all, you can test the exit code of `getent` directly.   `if getent passwd "$name" > /dev/null ; then ..... ; fi`.   Or, if you insist on grepping /etc/passwd directly because you've never heard of `getent` before and it's confusing and scary: `if grep -q "^$name:" /etc/passwd ; then ... ; fi` but you shouldn't do that, you should learn the right tool for the job.

Comment: BTW that `grep -q` should only be used if `$name` has been sanitised so that it doesn't contain any regex special characters like `.` or `*`.   or use `grep -Pq "^\Q$name\E:" /etc/passwd` (using perl regex \Q and \E to disable regex metacharacters in $name).   But you should still use getent instead of grepping /etc/passwd.

Comment: What if the user does not exist - create one with name from `newusers.txt`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your assistance
I have a text file with users under the name newusers.txt, I want to check if the user exist in /etc/passwd, If the user exist create a new user with new_existed_username, Struggling with this.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

NAME_REGEX='^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$'   # default value for adduser.conf
. /etc/adduser.conf              # "source" it in case local config is different

myuser='/home/yakyak/Desktop/Exercises/newusers.txt'

grep "$NAME_REGEX" "$myuser" | while read -r name; do
  while getent passwd "$name" > /dev/null; do
    name="new_$name"
  done

  # check if $name is > 32 characters
  if [ "${#name}" -gt 32 ] ; then
    echo "username '$name' is too long" > /dev/stderr
  else
    adduser --disabled-login --gecos '' "$name"
  fi
done
```

Instead of using `sed` to delete empty lines from your `newusers.txt` file, it uses `grep` to exclude invalid usernames, those which **don't** match a pattern stored in a shell variable called `$NAME_REGEX`.  It uses the same variable name (and regex pattern) as `adduser` itself for the definition of "valid".   See `man adduser.conf` and search for `NAME_REGEX`.

This will keep on pre-pending "new_" to $name until $name doesn't exist in the passwd db.  If "user" exists, it'll try "new_user". if "new_user" exists, it'll try "new_new_user". and then "new_new_new_user".  and so on.

The script uses `getent passwd`, but only cares about the exit code - the output is discarded (redirected to /dev/null).  If getent exits with 0 (true), then the user exists, so try again.

When `getent` returns false (i.e. `$name` doesn't already exist), it checks if the name is too long. If it is, it prints an error message.  If it isn't, it runs `adduser`.

BTW, the actual exit code we expect to see from getent is `0` for if the user already exists and `2` if the user does not exist.  In some circumstances, getent can return different exit codes (see `man getent`), but they're not possible with the way we're using getent (i.e. searching the `passwd` db AND providing a username).

---

A slightly better version would be to use a numeric suffix for the usernames.  e.g. using `printf` with a `%03i` format string for a 3-digit wide zero-padded number (e.g. `001`, `002`, etc). If you don't want it zero-padded, use `%i` instead.  The `count` variable is reset to zero in the outer while loop for each username processed.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

NAME_REGEX='^[a-z][-a-z0-9]*$'   # default value for adduser.conf
. /etc/adduser.conf              # "source" it in case local config is different

myuser='/home/yakyak/Desktop/Exercises/newusers.txt'

grep "$NAME_REGEX" "$myuser" | while read -r user; do
  name="$user"
  count=0

  while getent passwd "$name" > /dev/null; do
    let count+=1
    name="$(printf "%s%03i" "$user" "$count")"
  done

  # check if $user is > 32 characters
  if [ "${#name}" -gt 32 ] ; then
    echo "username '$name' is too long" > /dev/stderr
  else
    adduser --disabled-login --gecos '' "$name"
  fi
done
```

This version uses two variables for the username - `$user` for the name as read in from the newusers.txt file, and `$name` for the current username we're trying to use.   $name is initially copied from $user, and the inner while loop updates $name by incrementing the `$count` variable and appending it to `$user` whenever `getent` returns true.

---

Finally, neither of the above are particularly good scripts.  They do little more than the bare minimum required.   Personally, I'd be inclined to write it in perl rather than bash because [text processing in shell is a PITA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716).